# network connection using public key cryptography

Tags: cryptography, encryption, public-key-encryption

When `A` sends data to `B` over a network connection using public key cryptography, how does `A` achieve the goals of authentication, confidentiality ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a case like this, A is using B's public key, and B is using A's.

Confidentiality:  If A encrypts something using B's public key, then only somebody with B's private key can read it.  In practice, A is likely to generate a random key for some symmetric cipher like AES, since that's more efficient, but if encrypted with B's public key only A and B should have it.

Authentication:  This is more complicated.  In general, if you can send information confidentially, you can send authentication credentials.  Public key encryption can help, provided that A's public key is known to be A's for some reason.  Perhaps it's registered in a place B trusts for some reason, perhaps B has communicated with A before and wants to know if it's the same key.  Then A can send a message encrypted with A's private key, which can be read with A's public key.  This can be used as a cryptographic signature by hashing a message and encrypting the hash.

In these cases, I'm assuming that A and B have private and public keys, and that nobody else knows their private keys (and A doesn't know B's private key and vice versa).  If E knows A's private key, then E can send messages that appear to be from A, and E can read all private messages to A.  Moreover, if B doesn't know that A's public key is A's to begin with, B can't tell if E is doing a man-in-the-middle attack, by communicating with B with B's and E's public keys, communicating with A with A's and E's public keys, and relaying the communications.  This means that E can read (violating confidentiality) and change (violating authentication) communications between the two.  This is usually dealt with with certificates issued by a trusted certificate authority, which is getting out of scope of the question.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers and comments. they were very helpful.

Comment: Okay, I can concede that PKC can be used for authentication based on the fact that private keys must be held private (in order for it to really work).  However, I think that it must be made clear that this happens within the system as part of the network's infrastructure and not by user control - something that the question didn't address and the answer only alluded to.

Comment: @thosewhatnots:  I wasn't sure what level the OP wanted addressed, so I told how asymmetric ciphers can be used to aid authentication.  As far as user control goes, if I ssh to someplace I haven't sshed to before, I get a user-level warning.

Answer (score 0):

Read description of how SSL/TLS works. For example, you can read the [introductory article](http://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1948.php) on our site.

Comment: This also answers nothing.  I don't mind self-promotion when it's marked as such (and "our site" is marking it), but this is a link-only answer that explains nothing and adds nothing to SO.

Comment: @David read description of SSL as well, then you'll know what it does and what it doesn't.

Comment: I should be able to read a SO answer and get some enlightenment without going to an outside link.  You seem to be talking about my knowledge of communications security, which is entirely unrelated to the fact that your answer shouldn't be here, since it's not helpful by itself.